# Wordpress does not allowing to add menu items more than 80

Tags: wordpress, menu

Whenever I tried to add menu items more than 80 in Wordpress, It does not allow me to add and automatically removed menu position as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
max_input_vars  1000
```

in  .htaccess file

and follow this link

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/menu-items-disappearing/96593#96593